# check kind of class in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am updating one app to iOS 6 to iOS 7. But I am getting issue regarding kind of class. In iOS 6 it is showing class name custom button but in iOS 7 it displays _UITextContainerView.

```
    for (UIView *subView in textViewButton.subviews)
        {
            NSLog(@"yourObject is a: %@", [subView class]);
            @autoreleasepool
            {
                if([subView isKindOfClass:[CustomButton class]])
                {
                    CustomButton *button = (CustomButton*)subView;
                    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

                    [button setType:kButtonTypeQuestion];
                    button.titleLabel.font = kFontForContentPhone;
                    
                    if (button.tag == 62254 || button.tag == 62263)
                    {
                        CGRect tempFrame = button.frame;
                        tempFrame.origin.x = button.frame.origin.x - 3.0f;
                        
                        
                        button.frame = tempFrame;
                    }
                    if (self.soundFile != nil)
                    {
                        
                        CGRect tempFrame = button.frame;
                        tempFrame.size.width = button.frame.size.width + 28.0f;
                        button.frame = tempFrame;
                        [button setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0f, 30.0f, 5.0f, 10.0f)];
                    }
                }
            }
           }
```

**Update**

## pragma mark - Text Paragraph iPhone

```
    self.questionScrollView = [[CustomScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, currentYPosition, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height - currentYPosition - 60.0f)];
    self.questionScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    self.questionsContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.questionScrollView.frame.size.width, self.questionScrollView.frame.size.height)];
    currentYPosition = 0;
    
        for (Question *question in self.questions)
        {
            @autoreleasepool
            {
                self.ttmItem = [[TapToMoveItem alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, currentYPosition, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
                self.ttmItem.ttmDelegate = self;
                self.ttmItem.variant = self.exercise.variant;
                ttmItem.x_Position = question.x_position;
                ttmItem.y_Position = question.y_position;
                
                if ([question.sound_file length] > 0 || question.sound_file != nil)
                    self.ttmItem.hasAudio = YES;
                else
                    self.ttmItem.hasAudio = NO;
                
                if ([kPrefixImage isEqualToString:@"preint_"] && ([self.exercise.exercise_id integerValue] == 54 || [self.exercise.exercise_id integerValue] == 91)) {
                    ttmItem.soundFile = self.exercise.header_title;
                }
                
                self.ttmItem.prefix = question.prefix;
                self.ttmItem.text = question.text;
                self.ttmItem.longestPrefix = longestPrefix;
                
                self.ttmItem.longestAnswer = longestAnswer;
                self.ttmItem.buttonWidth = sizeForButton.width;
                
                //get and set answers
                ttmItem.answers = [self.answers objectForKey:question.question_id];
                
                [self.ttmItem createForPhone];
                
                [self.questionsContainer addSubview:self.ttmItem];
                
                currentYPosition += ttmItem.frame.size.height + SPACE_BET_VIEWS;
                
                //            itemHeight =  ttmItem.frame.size.height; //hack
                //            itemWidth =  ttmItem.frame.size.width;
                
                ttmCount++;
                
                
                if ([ttmItem.arrayOfTextViewButtons count] > 0) {
                    [dictionaryOfItemButtons setObject:ttmItem.arrayOfTextViewButtons forKey:question.question_id];
                }

            }
                            
        }
    
    
    self.questionsContainer.frame = CGRectMake(questionsContainer.frame.origin.x, questionsContainer.frame.origin.y, questionsContainer.frame.size.width, currentYPosition );
    
    [self.questionScrollView setContentSize:self.questionsContainer.frame.size];
    
    [self.questionScrollView addSubview:self.questionsContainer];
    [self addSubview:self.questionScrollView];
    [self setScrollEnabled:NO];
    
    
    
}
```

I am unable to find that why it is showing different in class name of any object. Moreover I didn't find any issue regarding this on google. Please help me if someone has an idea about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue isn't with `isKindOfClass`, it's the fact that the class is different.  Show how those views are created.

Comment: I don't see subviews being added to `self.textViewButton` in the new code.

Comment: From iOS7 UI objects have a extra wrapper/container, my solution was to do a loop until i found the right object but only when i detected an iOS7+ device

Comment: I don't really understand why you did not use the `IBOutletCollection` for storing your `CustomButton` objects; you would have had no issue with iteration at all.

Comment: In iOS 6 I got three subviews i.e. UIWEbdocumentview, uitextselectionview, custom button . but in iOS 7 it is showing only one subview i.e. _UITextContainerView with the same code @ShamsAhmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by doing this :

```
  for (UIView *subView in textViewButton.textInputView.subviews)
            {
                // const char* className = class_getName([yourObject class]);
                NSLog(@"yourObject is a: %@", [subView class]);
                @autoreleasepool
                {
                    if([subView isKindOfClass:[CustomButton class]])
                    {
                        CustomButton *button = (CustomButton*)subView;
                        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                        [button setType:kButtonTypeQuestion];

                        button.titleLabel.font = kFontForContentPhone;

                        if (button.tag == 62254 || button.tag == 62263)
                        {
                            CGRect tempFrame = button.frame;
                            tempFrame.origin.x = button.frame.origin.x - 3.0f;


                            button.frame = tempFrame;
                        }
                        if (self.soundFile != nil)
                        {

                            CGRect tempFrame = button.frame;
                            tempFrame.size.width = button.frame.size.width + 28.0f;
                            button.frame = tempFrame;
                            [button setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0f, 30.0f, 5.0f, 10.0f)];
                        }
                    }
                }
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the subviews as well until you found your object. if you happen to find the object exit the loop to save any unnecessary resources

```
for (UIView *subView in textViewButton.subviews)
{
    NSLog(@"yourObject is a: %@", [subView class]);
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[CustomButton class]])
        {
            CustomButton *button = (CustomButton*)subView;
            button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [button setType:kButtonTypeQuestion];
        button.titleLabel.font = kFontForContentPhone;

        if (button.tag == 62254 || button.tag == 62263)
        {
            CGRect tempFrame = button.frame;
            tempFrame.origin.x = button.frame.origin.x - 3.0f;


            button.frame = tempFrame;
        }
        if (self.soundFile != nil)
        {
            CGRect tempFrame = button.frame;
            tempFrame.size.width = button.frame.size.width + 28.0f;
            button.frame = tempFrame;
            [button setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0f, 30.0f, 5.0f, 10.0f)];
        }

    }
    else if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UITextContainerView")]) {
        // do a another loop
        for (UIView *innerSubViews in subView.subviews) {
            if([subView isKindOfClass:[CustomButton class]])
            {
                // call your custom button method here
                break; // stop inner loop 
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```